# pandas multiindex shift on filtered values

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get the time differences between rows of interest.

```
t = pd.data_range('1/1/2000', period=6, freq='D')
d = pd.DataFrame({'sid':['a']*3 + ['b']*3,
                  'src':['m']*3 + ['t']*3,
                  'alert_v':[1,0,0,0,1,1]}, index=rng)
```

- I want to get the time difference between rows where `alr`==1.
- Ive tried shifting, but are there other ways to take the difference between two rows in a column?
- i have tried simple lambdas and more complex .loc:

`

```
def deltat(g):
        g['d1'] = g[ g['alert_v']==1 ]['timeindex'].shift(1)
        g['d0'] = g[ g['alert_v']==1 ]['timeindex']
        return g['td'] = g['d1'] - g['d0']
d['td'] = d.groupby('src','sid').apply(lambda x: deltat(x) )


def indx(g):
        d0 = g.loc[g['alert_v']==1 ]
        d1[0] = d0[0]
        d1.append( d0[:-1] )

        g['tavg'] = g.apply( g.ix[d1,'timeindex'] - g.ix[d0,'timeindex'])
        return g
```

After trying a bunch of approaches, I cant seem to get past either the multigroup or filtering issues...

whats the best way to do this?

edit:

`diff(1)` produces this error:

```
 raise TypeError('incompatible index of inserted column '
 TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

while `shift(1)` produces this error:

```
 ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

attempt to clean the data, not help.

```
if any( pd.isnull( g['timeindex'] ) ):
            print '## timeindex not null'
        g['timeindex'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

Comment: You can also do `diff` but I think this line is unnecessary `g['d0'] = g[ g['alert_v']==1 ]['timeindex']
        return g['td'] = g['d1'] - g['d0']` as `shift` already calculates the difference so you should just return this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ***multindex group, select rows, diff, and insert new column*** **paradigm**: this is how I got it to work with clean output.

- some groups have 0 relevant rows, this throws an exception.
- shift throws key error, so just sticking with diff()

  ```
   # -- get the interarrival time
  def deltat(g):
      try:
          g['tavg'] = g[ g['alert_v']==1 ]['timeindex'].diff(1)
          return g
      except:
          pass
  d.sort_index(axis=0, inplace=True)
  d = d.groupby(['source','subject_id','alert_t','variable'],as_index=False,group_keys=False).apply( lambda x: deltat(x) )
  print d[d['alert_v']==1][['timeindex','tavg']]
  ```